# If $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, is $n$ squarefree?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, perfect-numbers

(I have asked a similar question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572152) around a week ago, but did not receive any responses.  I have therefore cross-posted it to this site, hoping to get some answers.)

An odd perfect number $N$ is said to be given in **Eulerian form** if $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ where $q$ is prime, $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and $\gcd(q, n) = 1$.

Here is my question:

> If $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, is $n$ squarefree?

I would certainly appreciate it if someone could point me to existing papers in the literature where this particular question is addressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, if an odd perfect number exists, then $n$ must contain a square factor. This is a 1937 result of Steuerwald:

R. Steuerwald, "Verschärfung einer notwendigen Bedingung für die Existenz einer
ungeraden vollkommenen Zahl," S.-B. Math.-Nat. Abt. Bayer. Akad. Wiss., 1937, pp. 68-73.

A very nice recent paper on this theme is by Fletcher, Nielsen, and Ochem (Math. Comp.); the preprint version is freely available on Nielsen's website: https://math.byu.edu/~pace/OPNSieves_web.pdf

[Edited as per Lucia's suggestion.]

Comment: It is absurd that someone chose to vote down this answer!  (It took me a little effort to parse your answer -- maybe it would be clearer if the first line said something like: ``No: if an odd perfect number exists, then $n$ must necessarily contain a square factor.")

Comment: Yes, that's clearer. I've made the edit.Thanks!

Comment: @so-calledfriendDon, mind if you check out this related [MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585550), where I ask if $n$ is a square?  Let me know if you need me to ask a separate MO question.

Comment: @so-calledfriendDon, here is the new [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227076).